# ldd: exited with unknown exit code when use qemu in docker

Tags: docker, qemu, ldd

I'm trying to use docker with qemu to build an arm image in my x86 host computer

I use arm64v8/ubuntu as the based image

I make a simple opencv program and try to use ldd command to see the dependencies.

however, ldd always shows:

> ldd: exited with unknown exit code (132)

ldd would work if I save this image and load it in an arm computer.

However, my main project's size is too large (or my arm computer's space is too small ) to import to the arm computer, I'd like to use ldd to find out which libraries are really necessary for this project.

I also try nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.4.4 as based image and ldd shows

> ldd: exited with unknown exit code (139)

what should I do to use ldd command if i'm in a arm image in the docker and my host computer is x86?

my dockerfile are like this:

```
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu
ENV TZ=Asia/Taipei
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \ 
    build-essential -y  \
    cmake -y  \
    git -y  \
    libgtk2.0-dev -y  \
    libjpeg-dev -y  \
    libpng-dev -y  \
    libtiff-dev -y  \
    pkg-config -y && \
    apt-get clean
WORKDIR /home/gino/
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    cd ./opencv && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake  \
        -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \ 
        -D WITH_QT=OFF \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=OFF \ 
        -D FORCE_VTK=OFF \
        -D WITH_TBB=OFF \ 
        -D WITH_GDAL=OFF \ 
    -D WITH_V4L=ON \
        -D WITH_XINE=OFF \ 
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
        -D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/gino/opencv_install \
        .. && \
    make -j8 && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig && \
    apt-get clean
WORKDIR /home/gino/
RUN rm -R ./opencv 
ADD ./ /home/gino/cvtest/
WORKDIR /home/gino/cvtest/

RUN make clean all

ENV HOME /home/developer
CMD /home/gino/cvtest/dockertest
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
    Mat frame;
    VideoCapture video(-1);
    while(video.isOpened())
    {
        video>>frame;
        imshow("frame",frame);
        waitKey(1);
    }
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```